# Get Colors by Message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command so when someone makes `#color [color_here]` (`#color ff00ff` responds with an embed with that color and an image with that color

**Code I have so far, but doesn't work:**

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def color(ctx, arg):
    author = ctx.message.author
    color = discord.Colour(0x + arg)
    embed=discord.Embed(name="COLOR", color=color)
    embed.set_author(name="Color Testing", icon_url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/464392471913168927/2e4866f48526dba93253b57326104a1b.png?size=2048')
    embed.add_field(name="**Color**:", value=color, inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Requested by {}".format(author), icon_url=author.avatar_url)
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `color = discord.Colour(int(f'0x{arg}', 16))` instead

Comment: It works, thanks man, if you want to be friends, msg me in discord SlimeYT#5408